# how to check if all elements in an array are 1 or -1 in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I want to check if all elements in an array are 1 or -1, and if even one of them is still any value except 1 or -1, the function should continue. I wrote this piece of code:

```
while (all(initial_color(:))~=1 || -1 )

THE FUNCTION

end
```

Initial_color is the name of the array.
But it is not working correctly, because I can see that all elements have turned to 1 or -1 but it still runs the function. I am new to Matlab, could you please help me with it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've never used Matlab, but from the looks of that statement, is it possible that it's evaluating (all(initial_color(:))~=1) OR (-1), and taking -1 to mean TRUE? You could try running it with: all(initial_color(:))~=1 AND all(initial_color(:))~=-1 to see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition to test for is as follows:

```
all( initial_color==1 | initial_color==-1 )
```

Here you create two arrays, one is true for all elements of value 1, one is true for all elements of value -1. The `|` element-wise OR operator combines these into a single array. All of the elements must be true, hence `all`.

You can also use `unique`, which returns the sorted set of unique values. This must be either `[-1,1]`, `[1]` or `[-1]`. `setdiff` then can remove the elements `-1` and `1` from the set, if the result is empty, there are no values different from 1 or -1:

```
u = unique(initial_color);
u = setdiff(u,[-1,1]);
result = isempty(u);
```

Note that `unique` is actually redundant here, `setdiff` returns the unique set also. This makes it a little easier to convert into a one-liner that fits within your `while`:

```
isempty(setdiff(initial_color,[-1,1]))
```

The `setdiff` approach is likely faster than the two comparisons, but I haven't tested this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function like [`abs`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/abs.html):

```
while (all(abs(initial_color(:))==1))
```

Or [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) / [`ismembertol`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismembertol.html).

Comment: I would recommend [`ismembertol`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismembertol.html) in the presence of floating point numbers.